# What's the difference between lazy loading and lazy evaluation?

Tags: terminology, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

Is there a difference between "lazy loading" and "lazy evaluation" (both of which are tags on Stack Overflow), or are they synonymous?

**Response to comment:** The tag wikis (which I'd looked at before asking the question) has the former referring to deferring of initialization, and the other talked about deferring of evaluation. Is it possible to initialize something without evaluating it?

Comment: If you mouse over the tag in SO, it will tell you the meaning.

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer I think those descriptions were pulled from wikipedia, and probably deserve some explanation (or maybe the wiki articles should be expanded ...)

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer: I've edited the question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lazy evaluation refers to how expressions are evaluated.  For example:

```
f(x) && g(x)
```

`g(x)` will not be called unless f(x) is true.

Lazy loading refers to initializing objects only when they are needed

Comment: Isn't `f(x) && g(x)` also called short-circuit evaluation? Or is short-circuit evaluation a subset of lazy evaluation?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm short circuit evaluation is a special case of lazy evaluation

Comment: Without meaning to be pedantic, is initializing an object a matter of calling expressions, meaning that lazy loading is a sub-case of lazy evaluation?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Lazy loading is a larger design concept.  For example, you can choose to preload content at the beginning of a program, or wait to load the content until when it is needed.  Lazy evaluation works at the micro-level.